# Spacy - Entity Linking using descriptions from Wikipedia

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using the example from here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/bin/wiki_entity_linking.

There is a flag for using descriptions from Wikipedia instead of Wikidata. I set this to True (it should get descriptions from the Wikipedia data). But looking at the code under the Wikidata section,

```
if not descr_from_wp:
    logger.info("STEP 4c: Writing Wikidata entity descriptions to {}".format(entity_descr_path))
    io.write_id_to_descr(entity_descr_path, id_to_descr)
```

This should not run because the `if` statement is `False`. But under the Wikipedia section,

```
if descr_from_wp:
    logger.info("STEP 5b: Parsing and writing Wikipedia descriptions to {}".format(entity_descr_path))
```

It just logs something -- it doesn't actually seem to create the descriptions. And the output file has the headers: `WD_id|description`.

How can I get it to write the Wikipedia descriptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe all the action happens in the line before the one you quoted:

```
wp.create_training_and_desc(wp_xml, entity_defs_path, entity_descr_path, 
training_entities_path, descr_from_wp, limit_train)
```

(this is [https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/master/nel-wikipedia/wikidata_pretrain_kb.py#L142])

That funtion is one file over, at https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/master/nel-wikipedia/wikidata_processor.py#L176:

```
def create_training_and_desc(
    wp_input, def_input, desc_output, training_output, parse_desc, limit=None
):
    wp_to_id = io.read_title_to_id(def_input)
    _process_wikipedia_texts(
        wp_input, wp_to_id, desc_output, training_output, parse_desc, limit
    )
```

That being said, having gone through this process a few days ago, I did get the impression that it's all in flux and there may be a bit of a mismatch between descriptions, the actual code, and versions of spacy. You may have noticed that the Readme starts with the instruction "Run wikipedia_pretrain_kb.py". And yet, such a file does not exist, only wikidata_pretrain_kb.py.

While the process did work (ventually), the final training progresses at a glacial speed of 10 seconds per example. For 300,000 examples in the training set, that would imply about a year of training at the default 10 epochs.

There are some instructions that suggest one isn't intended to run *all* the training data that's available. But in that case it seems strange to run 10 epochs on a repeating set of data with diminishing rates of return.

(Updated URLs Nov 2020. This example did not make it over from v2 -> v3 (yet?))

Comment: Do you know if there is a way this can be done without Wikidata?

Comment: Actually, I am able to get training data (which is really what I want), but all the "entities" are empty, even though I know that the model I am using recognizes them.

Comment: Haven’t gotten that far yet. Also pretty new with spacy. First idea: are you loooking in the right place? I. E. Not at where POS-labels are stored?

Comment: In case someone comes across this - I'd like to point out that this code was moved to https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/master/nel-wikipedia (spaCy v2).

Comment: Thanks, @SofieVL! I have updated the URLs. I'm not sure at what "kharma level" one picks up the ability to edit others' answers, but assuming you have that option, I would not have minded.